# Is it possible to use variables in a .replace() function?

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I am trying to use the replace() function to iterate through a spreadsheet, store a cell value in a variable called "cell", reference the "cell" variable in the replace() function to replace any string called $ipaddr in a text file.

I've tried changing the type using str() etc.

```py
for i in range (1,3):
    for string in fileinput.input(["file" + str(i) + ".txt"], inplace=True):
        cell = ws.cell(row=i, column=1)
        print(string.replace("$ipaddr", cell.value, end="")
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
replace() takes no keyword arguments
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Coding\string_replace.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(string.replace("$ipaddr", cell.value, end=""))
```

Comment: `print(string.replace("$ipaddr", cell.value), end="")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer comes from **MrGeek's comment**:

print(string.replace("$ipaddr", cell.value), end=""). – MrGeek Sep 17 at 8:58